# Linux command on changing ownership and displaying files

Tags: linux, file-permissions, file-ownership

Hi I am new to Linux and I need to learn how to perform these 3 tasks

```sh
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  staff     108 Oct 17 21:28 coolstuff.o
```

1. Change permissions so that *user* can read/write/execute, *group* can read/execute and *other* can execute. Assume you are not logged in as the `root` superuser and you are not user `user1`.
2. Change ownership from `user1` to `user2`. Assume you are not logged in as the `root` superuser and you are not `user1` or `user2`.
3. List all the `.o` files (and no other files) in this directory (assuming you are currently in the directory), making sure that the permission information for them is shown (as in the example above). This is useful when making sure that the file permission and ownership changes occurred as expected and that other files are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

To change directory permissions in Linux, use the following:

```
    chmod +rwx filename to add permissions.
    chmod -rwx directoryname to remove permissions.
    chmod +x filename to allow executable permissions.
    chmod -wx filename to take out write and executable permissions
```

The command for changing directory permissions for group owners is similar, but add a “g” for group or “o” for users:

```
chmod g+w filename
chmod g-wx filename
chmod o+w filename
chmod o-rwx foldername
```

for changing permission from user1 to user2

```
chown name filename
```

for only .o file with permissions

```
 ls -l *.o
```

Comment: Can these commands work even when you are not log in as root or the owner of the file?

Comment: For the 1st question, you need to be logged in as root user

Comment: @Anime_boy: Change permission can be made only by somebody who has ownership of the files. Either they are the owners or the group owning the file/directory. By default `root` is the owner of everything. But if you don't have `root`, you can use `sudo` or be in some relationship with the owner (as last resort, maybe through a process you control that runs with a higher elevated permissions than you have over that file/directory)